# CKEditor returns a value as array

Tags: forms, 10

In my Form I have this entry that presents a CKEditor instance

```
$form['notes'] = array(
    '#input_format' => '1',
    '#rows' => '5',
    '#type' => 'text_format',
    '#base_type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Reminder Notes'),
  );
```

In the "values" array within my submit method I have this:

```
$form_state->getValue('notes'),
```

But when it saves the data it comes in with only the word "Array"

The install file schema is like this:

```
  'notes' => [
    'type' => 'text',
    'size' => 'medium',
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => 'Notes to aid in managing the reminder',
  ],
```

How can I get this to save the data correctly rather than just giving the word "Array"?

Comment: The array will have `value` and `format` keys, you need to save both values to render the result later on

Comment: What is the implementation of the submit function?

Comment: You need to define '#default_value' or '#value' in the array.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define `#default_value` or `#value` as below

```
$form['notes'] = [
  '#type' => 'text_format',
  '#title' => $this->t('Reminder Notes'),
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#format' => 'filtered_html',
  '#rows' => 5,
];
```

Then in your install file schema

```
function mymodule_schema() {
  $schema = array();

  // Define your custom table.
  $schema['mytable'] = array(
    'description' => 'Table for storing reminders',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'description' => 'Reminder notes',
      ),
      'notes' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'not null' => FALSE,
        'size' => 'big',
        'description' => 'notes to aid in managing the reminder',
      ),
      // Add other fields as needed.
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```